# Is there a way to host a Blogger blog at the apex domain?

Tags: domains, blogger

Is there a way to host a Blogger blog at the apex domain? I want to map `http://example.com/` to `http://example.blogspot.com/`.

Unfortunately, Google does not support the use of the apex domain with Blogger.

I do not wish to host the blog at an address using the *www* or a different subdomain. I only want to use the apex domain.

**SOLVED:** I previously requested that Google update their documentation at https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/1233387. They have done so. I had hoped that it might be possible to host a Blogger blog at the apex domain using a third party DNS provider. This does not appear to be supported. Google only supports *forwarding* traffic from the apex domain to a Blogger blog hosted at a *subdomain*.

**It is NOT possible to host a Blogger blog at the apex domain.**

Comment: The documentation you've linked to explains how to update your DNS records to support this. Under "Step 2", "Use a top level domain" the optional steps 9 and 10 allow this.

Answer (score 3):

> Google does not support the use of the apex domain with Blogger.

The Blogger help page for "[Change to a custom domain](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/55374?hl=en)" appears to suggest you can:

> Optional: You can also enter A-records, which link your naked domain (example.com) to an actual site (www.example.com).
>
> Enter your domain name in the format example.com, and list the IP addresses shown below in the "A" section. You'll need to add four separate A-records which point to four different Google IPs.
>
> 216.239.32.21
>   216.239.34.21
>   216.239.36.21
>   216.239.38.21

However, as pointed out by Stephen in comments, the [Blogger Help document for "Use a custom domain"](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/1233387) states:

> 3. Type the URL of the domain you've purchased, keeping in mind that it *must* begin with **www** in order to work.
>
> :
>
> 10. *Optional:* You can also enter **A-records**, which links your naked domain (example.com) to an actual site (www.example.com). **If you skip this step, visitors who leave off the "www" will see an error page.**

So, it would seem that the www subdomain is mandatory after all for Blogger sites, and setting an `A` record is almost a "recommended" step in order to get the apex domain to work at all for your Blogger site.

Comment: The [documentation](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/1233387) says "Type the URL of the domain you've purchased, keeping in mind that it must begin with www in order to work."  Even though they support A records, they say they don't support no-www.  It doesn't help that that doc uses the term "top-level-domain" incorrectly.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks, the docs are a bit confus(ing|ed). I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, blogger does not support hosting your blog at the naked/apex address. Neither is it recommended to do so - most contents will be hosted at http://www.example.com

The recommended way is to add a CNAME DNS entry to redirect the naked/apex domain to `www` or whichever subdomain you have chosen for your blog.

[image: Blogger redirect naked domain]

Comment: The [documentation](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/1233387) appears to suggest you must set an `A` record (not a "CNAME DNS entry") in order direct the naked/apex domain to your Blogger site. What happens if you _uncheck_ the "Redirect example.com to www.example.com"?