# Why is my naked domain in blogger redirecting to discord.com and not to my www-domain?

Tags: 301-redirect, cloudflare, blogger

The problem is that I added my custom domain name in blogger like google mentioned I added 4 "A" records and 2 "CNAME" but in the end I can't access my website through the naked domain because it's redirecting me to discord.com,

[image]

I have trying the setup in the domain provider dashboard and now I have changed the nameservers to point at Cloudflare to maybe fix it there by repeating the process but nothing seems to remove this discord redirect and I don't know where is it.

I have tried with a different blogger address with a different different template but the redirect is still there.

I tried the redirect from non to www in blogger settings but this error is showing

"Save Failed Naked domain redirection already exists. Please check other usage of the domain."

I have tried adding a rule in Cloudflare to redirect but it doesn't work either

[image]

Comment: See also: [Is there a way to host a Blogger blog at the apex domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/105663/is-there-a-way-to-host-a-blogger-blog-at-the-apex-domain)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your page rule at CloudFlare to work, you need to change the proxy status for your A records from "DNS only" to "Proxied." Click on the icon in the "Proxy status" column to change them. Proxied records will be handled by Cloudflare's web servers.

I'm pretty sure that is the only change you need to make to get Cloudflare to start redirecting your domain apex to the www subdomain.   See [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/113180/how-to-avoid-ssl-warnings-about-certificate-not-for-the-current-site-when-redire/129449#129449) where I give step by step instructions for setting up redirects using Cloudflare.